# Angular Firebase check if token has been revoked

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Angular app, I have a guard that checks if the user exists and if the email is verified. Then it does the redirections accordingly.

Here's the code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
return this.apiService.getCurrentUser().pipe(map(user => {
  if (user !== null) {
    if (user.isEmailVerified) {
      return true
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([VERIFICATION_PATH], { queryParams: { 'redirectURL': state.url } })
      return false
    }
  } else {
    this.routerService.params = { queryParams: { 'redirectURL': state.url } }
    this.router.navigate([CONNECTION_PATH], { queryParams: { 'redirectURL': state.url } })
    return false
  }
}))
```

}

Now I would like to check if the **token has been revoked**. I've seen that I can use the admin sdk but I would like to do it with the client sdk if possible. I wasn't able to find a way.